# Getting radio button value and storing in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is radio button code 
now what if radio button does not have a constant name  how would i store the data in database because to  store the data in database we will need a name of form attribute

```
$sql1="select * from questions where email='". $_SESSION['email']    ."'";
 $row=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

 while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row))
{
 ?>

<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo   $result['qid'].".".$result['question'];?></h2>

 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer1'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer2'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>

  <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
```

if we know the name of radio button we can access it using

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>"  name="name"><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
 $name=$_POST['name'];
```

but in the above code name of radio button is not fixed.questions is the table which consists of qid and questions with multiple options that is answer1,answer2 etc

i want to store the option select by user into database.for which i need to know the name of radio button
how should i use post in this case

```
$name=$_POST['what should go in here'];
```

Comment: u can try it `name="radio[<?php echo $result['qid'];?>]"` in php `print_r($_POST['radio'])` will return the radio input array

Comment: or u can also check it: `name="radio[answer1][<?php echo $result['qid'];?>]"` and so on...

Comment: ok but how to ascess the name variable using post to insert the radio value to database.     insert into answer (answer) value('{$_POST['what sholud be here']}');

Comment: `$_POST['radio']['answer1']` this should be the ist value of radio

Comment: tired something like this                                                                      <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>" name="radio[answer1][<?php echo $result['qid'];?>]"<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>"  name="radio[answer1][<?php echo $result['qid'];?>]"><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>               <input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php 
$rate=$_POST['radio']['answer1'];
if($_POST['submit'])
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO answer (answer)
VALUES ('{$rate}')";

Comment: instead of gettinf radio button value in database it says ARRAY in answer column@devpro

Comment: ok let me chk .... do u want to store all answers?

Comment: hmm, this is radio, and u will get the one value from the radio value right

Comment: yaa its radio and i sholud get one option selected by user into database there are total of four options for each question

Comment: answer updated, u can change it as per your values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125075/discussion-between-devpro-and-sumanth-reddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the radio button value along with question ID as:

**Basic Example:**

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2); // your Question ID array
?>
```

**Your Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
foreach ($array as $key => $qid) {
?>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio[<?=$qid?>]">
Answer 1

<input type="radio" value="2" name="radio[<?=$qid?>]">
Answer 2

<input type="radio" value="3" name="radio[<?=$qid?>]">
Answer 3

<input type="radio" value="4" name="radio[<?=$qid?>]">
Answer 4
<?php
echo "<br/>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

**In PHP:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $query = array();
  foreach ($_POST['radio'] as $key => $value) {
     $query[] = "('$value','$key')";
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (answer,questionID) VALUES ";
  $sql .= implode(",", $query);
  echo $sql;
}
?>
```

In this example query look like:

```
INSERT INTO table (answer,questionID) VALUES ('2','1'),('3','2')
```

---

*Few Suggestions:*

*- Your code is open for SQL Injection, you must need to prevent your code with SQL Attack and this reference will help you to understand: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

*- Make sure your column name and table name not having any conflict, currently, you are using same name for both.*

---

**Update with Your Code:**

```
<?php
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row))
{
?>
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['qid'].".".$result['question'];?></h2>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer1'];?>"  name="radio[<?php  echo $result['qid'];?>]">
<?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer2'];?>"  name="radio[<?php  echo $result['qid'];?>]">
<?php echo $result['answer2'];?>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>"  name="radio[<?php  echo $result['qid'];?>]">
<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>"  name="radio[<?php  echo $result['qid'];?>]">
<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
<? 
}
?>
```

**In PHP:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $query = array();
  foreach ($_POST['radio'] as $key => $value) {
     $query[] = "('$value','$key')";
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (answer,questionID) VALUES ";
  $sql .= implode(",", $query);
  echo $sql; // run this query in mysqli_query()
}
?>
```

***Few More Instructions:***

*- Change the table name as per your table name*

*- Change the column name according to your column.*

*- Use INSERT query at once, no need to use it inside the loop.*

Comment: i will try it thaks

Comment: no i did'nt i found @kerv method much easier and thanks fro help

Comment: @sumanthreddy: no, because he is using mysqli_query inside the loop, it means, your query will run multiple times, u can use only one single query.

Comment: ohh in that case can u explain ur code by using my code so it would be easy for me

Comment: @sumanthreddy: first of all tell me, u just want to save answer, or answer along with quersion id? in Database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125080/discussion-between-devpro-and-sumanth-reddy).

Comment: what if table also conatins email and email is session variable hoe to add it the database

Comment: @sumanthreddy: u can add email field also. and add column in query to

Answer (score 0):

Create an array at the end of while loop like this :

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row))
{
  ?>

<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['qid'].".".$result['question'];?></h2>

 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer1'];?>"  name="<?php  echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer2'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer3'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>

<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['answer4'];?>"  name="<?php echo $result['qid'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
<? $names[] = $result['qid'];

}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

for ($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++) {
if(isset($_POST[$names[$i]]) {
$rate = $_POST[$names[$i]];

$sql ="INSERT INTO answer (answer, qid) VALUES (".$rate.", ".$names[$i] .")";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);



}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: am new to php can u explain how to use the $names[ ]  array in query to insert the value into database

Comment: i would probably use a for loop for your query like this

for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO answer (answer) VALUES ($names[$i])";
***run your query here***

}

Comment: you say that i need to write query to insert values to data base inside the for loop??

Comment: Yea, if i understand correctly. you want to insert all the different values

Comment: there are questions which have mutliple options then the value selected by the user for every question should be stored in the database to a column named answer

Comment: can you please help what to do after the names array is created explain with the my above code please

Comment: oh ok sorry i didnt understand your question. I am gonna update my answer.

Comment: bro, u need to modify this line `mysqli_query($sql);` mysqli_query needs two params.

Comment: what if i want to also add qid to database ...something like insert into answer (qid,answer)values('{rate}','{what sholud be here}');       that i s want to the question id to which user answered

Comment: @sumanthreddy: yes, i asked u, do u want to insert questionid and answer together

Comment: what change did you made and where

Comment: Adding $names[$i] to the query and making sure that $_POST[$names[$i]] is set